# Getting QWidget from Another App?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ipc, inter-process-communicat

I have App1, where I have some QWidgets (as containers). In App2 there are some other widgets like QLabel, QCheckBox and so on. App2 should be able to show its widgets in my app.

Any idea how can I do it?

I tried to get WId of picked widget (by using winId() method) and create a windowContainer for that widget, but there are a lot of problems with this method.

I can't do this by using QWidget::find(WId id) because this is in-process, and App1 and App2 are separate processes.

Comment: The widget itself will be bound to its own application. But you could keep the content on SHM including metadata on the widget. In your "Viewer" App you could now just rebuild that widget using this metadata and content.

Comment: You need to write some type of protocol between to the two widgets.  You can do this w/ SHM as Sebastian suggested, or another way would be to use QTcpSocket and communicate that way.  This isn't really unique to Qt, but programming in general.

Comment: @never_ever what you're asking for is a recommendation of interprocess communication protocol. If you're going to remain on Windows only I'd strongly encourage you to consider .net (maybe even mono if you will be multi-platform.) This will not be a simple process and is well beyond the scope of what a single answer can address.